# Find adjacent cells on raster and compare altitude

Tags: r

I would like to obtain a list of neighbouring cells for raster data. Below is a simple and intuitive way of doing it using the `adjacent()` from the `gdistance` library. This function however only allows finding neighbouring cells for *one* specified cell. To obtain neighbouring cells for all, I use a nested loop which is horribly inefficient for large data sets. How could I do this more efficiently? I thought about `apply` but have not managed. The goal is to compare the altitude of each cell on the grid.

```
library(raster)
library(gdistance) # package for adjacent function

# make the blank raster, the extents and resolution of which are up to you.
# the cells are numbered 1 to ncell (starting in the top left in R)
r <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=6,ymn=0,ymx=6,res=c(2,2))
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)


adj_cells <- c() # initialise vector to store adjacent cells
adj_cells_temp <- c() # initialise second vector to store adjacent cells for each row on the grid
system.time(
  for(i in 1:r@nrows){
    for(j in 1:r@ncols){
      adj_cells_temp <- as.data.frame(adjacent(r, cells=c(i, j), directions=8, pairs=T))
      adj_cells <- rbind(adj_cells, adj_cells_temp)
    }
  }
)
```

The result also includes duplicates which is not helpful to increase efficiency.

Comment: This sounds like some sort of "focal" operator. See the `focal` function for more.

Comment: thank you for the input